# Value of Unpassed post param in Java restlet?

Tags: java, post, restlet

Am a newbie to Java & Restlet.

Am writing a function to get the post params and calls another function internally.

My doubt is if my code is something like this:

```
Form form = new Form(entity);
String abc = form.getFirstValue("abc");
```

And if the param abc is not passed, what would be the exception or what would be stored in abc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this source code: [Series](https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/blob/master/modules/org.restlet/src/org/restlet/util/Series.java). Your [Form](http://restlet.org/learn/javadocs/2.1/jse/api/org/restlet/data/Form.html?is-external=true) class extends this Series class.

If parameter 'abc' not exists, then **null** (defaultValue) will be returned:

```
public String getFirstValue(String name) {
    return getFirstValue(name, false);
}

public String getFirstValue(String name, boolean ignoreCase) {
    return getFirstValue(name, ignoreCase, null);
}

public String getFirstValue(String name, boolean ignoreCase, String defaultValue) {
    String result = defaultValue;
    NamedValue<String> param = getFirst(name, ignoreCase);

    if ((param != null) && (param.getValue() != null)) {
        result = param.getValue();
    }

    return result;
}
```